# 2 Capturing groups with a multiples catch on the second that is separated by unwanted char

Tags: regex, ksh

I'm trying to catch multiples times a capturing group that follows another one or himself. I can have multiples times the same string over and over. Let's just take the following one for tests :

```
 thing: random1_abcd
                abcd_n1p3; abcd_n2p1


"random2_abcd" does not exist.
 thing:  random3_abcd
                abcd_n1p1; abcd_n2p3

 thing: random4_abcd
                abcd_n1p3; abcd_n3p1; abcd_n2p7

 thing:  random5_abcd
                abcd_n4p2; abcd_n3p3; abcd_n6p7; abcd_n1p6
```

I want to catch  **abcd_X** foreach **randomX_abcd** (and knowing the bound between them). I must not catch the **"random2_abcd"** since it does not exist !

Here is what I've so far : `(\w*_abcd)` is to capture the **randomX_abcd**. I got `(abcd_\w*)` to capture the **abcd_X** part. At first I tried to catch evey abcd_X separated. So I used `(\w*_abcd)\s*(?: (abcd_\w*);?)+` but it only catch the last **abcd_X** since it's greedy. It's not going for multiples catch on the second group. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/7LpAUM/2)

Now I'm trying to just get 2 groups (no more multiples matches with the same capturing groups : one with **randomX_abcd** and another with the corresponding **abcd_X list**. There is a tricky part : it might have multiples spaces and new line. But it might have just one space. So I can not rely on the newline part.
Given the new idea I came up to this :

```
(\w*_abcd)\s*((?: ?abcd_\w*;?)+)
```

Which is working fine but I'm wondering. Is it possible to achieve my first idea : to catch the same **randomX_abcd** with every distinct **abcd_X**  ?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Because a regex index is advanced to the right after a successful match. You cannot match several times at the same index in the string. Is it the answer you expect?

Comment: Ok I understand thank you.

Comment: Note that this is possible with Perl6 regex that can get any kind of overlapping matches even starting at the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because a regex index is advanced to the right after a successful match. You cannot match several times at the same index in the string.